# should prototypes be used with a self-executing anonymous function

Tags: javascript

I've programmed a lot in C++ and Java before and am getting into Javascript a lot more these days.

I've been reading up on different class definition patterns in Javascript and am familiar (but not exactly comfortable) with javascript's prototype property.

I also read this article which I found very useful:

[How Good C# Habits can Encourage Bad JavaScript Habits:
Part 1](http://enterprisejquery.com/2010/10/how-good-c-habits-can-encourage-bad-javascript-habits-part-1/)

Specifically scrolling down to the Self-Executing Anonymous Function: Part 2 (Public & Private) section, which I like quite a bit.

This pattern however makes no use of javascript prototyping. I'm wondering if the two can or should be reconciled?

For example, I've declared a 'module' called mycharts that will have several charts in it. The first chart is a barChart. I have the following simplified code:

```
(function(mycharts, $, undefined) {
  mycharts.barChart = function(containerDiv, data) {

      // private variables specific to a given chart instance
      var chart = {};
      var _containerDiv = containerDiv;
      var _data = data;      
      var _barColor = 'blue';   // default color is blue

      // public getter/setter accessor
      chart.barColor = function(_) {
        if (!arguments.length) return _barColor;
        _barColor = _;
        return chart;
      };

      // public method
      chart.render = function() {    
        drawChart(_data.table, _data.values);
      };

      // private method
      function drawChart(table, values) {
        ...
      }

      return chart;
}(window.mycharts = window.mycharts || {}, $));
```

In this example I have one 'class', barChart which has three 'methods', barColor() and render() (public) and drawChart() (private). None of the methods are defined using javascript's prototype property.

My question is: should I be using prototype or not for any or all of these methods?

**Update:** Based on the answers and comments here is how a client would use this module:

```
var chart1 = mycharts.barChart('#chart1', data_set1)
                     .barColor('red');

var chart2 = mycharts.barChart('#chart2', data_set2)
                     .barColor('green'); 

chart1.render();
chart2.render();
```

And yes, I updated the original code snippet to return chart (oops, I missed that line). So the individual instances of the chart object will be returned every time mycharts.barChart() is called.

**Update 2:** Adding 'public' methods to the prototype seems straightforward enough. Just define it very similarly to as originally described above in the self-executing anonymous function. Eg:

```
chart.prototype.render() = function() {...};
```

But what's the correct way to do this for the 'private' methods? I understand that private isn't truly enforced, but the original code above makes their use outside of the 'class' context inconvenient, so if possible I would like to keep my private methods as 'private' as possible.

Comment: How do you use this code? Do you return `chart` when calling `mycharts.barChart()`?

Comment: I would say put it directly on the chart object . I don't think you gain anything by using the prototype.

Comment: @alex I updated the code (forgot the 'return chart;' statement) and added an example client usage. So it sounds like using prototype would be better so there aren't many copies of the chart functions floating around. Sound right to you?

Comment: @lostdorje Yeah, basically. It also means you can keep the different properties on the object and let the methods live once on the prototype.

Comment: @alex Thanks. In my 2nd update, still wondering about how to add 'private' methods to chart.prototype...Is it possible to keep the private semantics with the private methods above and add them to the prototype too?

Answer (score 3):

What are your criteria for "should"?

Prototype inheritance is good if you are going to make multiple instances, otherwise closures (and the "module pattern") are good for singletons and "private" members.

Just remember that "private" in javascript doesn't provide any security, it's just a convenience for values and methods that you don't want public (e.g. you might have methods that are intended to only work in the context of the object and aren't used externally, or values that should be shared and you don't want to pass them around).

The beauty of javascript is that you can use a variety of OO patterns in the one program, using what suits best in each circumstance. It's not a matter of one or the other, but what suits best in a certain case. Look through the code of the more highly regarded libraries and you'll see most (all?) of them mix up prototypes, modules and plain object properties.

Answer (score 0):

If you always return the `chart` object, then you could benefit from defining those methods on its `prototype` once and just returning a new object which has that as its prototype.